# Python Selenium - Select value from drop down menu

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, drop-down-menu, css-selectors

I want to select a value from a drop down menu that has several menus inside it
[image]

I use the following code:

```
# CLICK ARROW
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#WIN_7_1000000217 > a:nth-child(3)').click()
# 1ST MENU
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.MenuOuter:nth-child(7) > div:nth-child(2) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(6)')))
menu_1 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.MenuOuter:nth-child(7) > div:nth-child(2) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(6)')
actions.move_to_element(menu_1).click().perform()
# 2ND MENU
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.MenuOuter:nth-child(11) > div:nth-child(2) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1)')))
menu_2 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.MenuOuter:nth-child(9) > div:nth-child(2) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1)')
actions.move_to_element(menu_2).click().perform()
# 3RD MENU
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'tr.MenuTableRow:nth-child(35)')))
menu_3 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'tr.MenuTableRow:nth-child(35)')
actions.move_to_element(menu_3).click().perform()
```

However I am not able to select the second menu, its CSS_SELECTOR is:

> *div.MenuOuter:nth-child(9) > div:nth-child(2) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1)*

Sometimes it works this way but the problem is that CSS_SELECTOR changes every time the number of the first *nth-child*, sometimes it's 9, 11 or 12... Is there a way to solve this and locate the element I want?

Html code for the second menu visible in the image:

```
<div class="MenuScrollUp" style="background-image: url(&quot;../../../../resources/images/menu_up.gif&quot;); width: 62px; visibility: hidden;"></div>
<div class="MenuTableContainer">
   <table class="MenuTable" style="width: 62px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tbody class="MenuTableBody">
         <tr class="MenuTableRow">
            <td class="MenuEntryNameHover" nowrap="">IT Support</td>
            <td class="MenuEntrySubHover" style="background-image:url(&quot;../../../../resources/images/menu_sub.gif&quot;)" arsubmenu="0">&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
<div class="MenuScrollDown" style="background-image: url(&quot;../../../../resources/images/menu_down.gif&quot;); width: 62px; visibility: hidden;"></div>
```

Html code for ESI - Espirito Santo Informatica and IBM Outsourcing:

```
<div class="MenuTableContainer">
    <table class="MenuTable" style="width: 174px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody class="MenuTableBody">
            <tr class="MenuTableRow">
                <td class="MenuEntryName" nowrap="">ESI - Espirito Santo Informatica</td>
                <td class="MenuEntrySub" style="background-image:url(&quot;../../../../resources/images/menu_sub.gif&quot;)" arsubmenu="4">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="MenuTableRow">
                <td class="MenuEntryName" nowrap="">IBM Outsourcing</td>
                <td class="MenuEntrySub" style="background-image:url(&quot;../../../../resources/images/menu_sub.gif&quot;)" arsubmenu="5">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Is URL public ?

Comment: Nope, sorry :((

Comment: Need to see HTML to give you proper solution

Comment: Can you do it with text shown in the menu ? Like Select `IBM Outsourcing` based on text... something like `//div[contains(text(), 'IBM Outsourcing')]` - this is just a typical xpath

Comment: I added the html code from the second menu visible in the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not **xpath** ?

```
//td[contains(text() , 'IT Support')]
```

something like this :

```
# 2ND MENU
actions.move_to_element(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[contains(text() , 'IT Support')]")))).click().perform()
```

Comment: Actually, it worked the first 3 times and then it stopped working... ://

Comment: What is the error when it did not work ? and Are you doing the same with menu 1 and 3 ?

Comment: I added 60 to the Wait and it returns TimeOutException... No, because it's menu 2 that's causing the problem so far

Comment: How are you selecting the Menu 1 ? after click on arrow

Comment: Yes, I'm selecting menu 1 which makes menu 2 visible

Comment: You need to change this line `div.MenuOuter:nth-child(7) > div:nth-child(2) > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(6)` write xpath or a reliable css

Comment: I replace the 3 lines from my code in the menu 2 section by the code you gave me

Comment: Can you share HTML for IBM Outsourcing also ?

Comment: The way I interact with menu 1 works, the CSS_SELECTOR reference never changes opposite of menu 2

Comment: let me have a look, I will get back to you

Comment: Thank you very much for your support and availability! But this is confusing me because I don't understand what's going on, I didn't change anything and it worked again... Is the use of selenium really that unstable?

Comment: Did you try to replace the code for Menu 1 like this : `//td[contains(text(), 'IBM Outsourcing')]`  and use it like this `actions.move_to_element(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[contains(text(), 'IBM Outsourcing')]")))).click().perform()` - Probably you do not even have to click there, Is it just hover ?

Comment: and Selenium is not that much unstable, it could be locator or may be even web application

Comment: I'm going to try replacing the code for menu 1, but I remove the .click and the .perform?

Comment: How do you interact with Menu 1  when you click on down arrow ? Is it like you just have to hover to `IBM Outsourcing` and then you second menu is visible or you have to click manually on `IBM Outsourcing` and then second menu is visible

Comment: I just have to hover if it's me doing it

Comment: then remove `.click` but keep `.perform()`

Comment: Looks like this one is working!! I will continue testing, but I don't think there is a problem

Comment: Sure, let me know if there is. or May be you can create new ticket as well in future, that will have bit more audience

Comment: No joke, but it works 1 time in 2... When it blocks it's always in menu 2, and it returns TimeoutException

Comment: You have to determine in Menu 2 do you really have to click or hover manually ?

Comment: Manually, I just have to hover. I also took off the .click()

Comment: and still it's inconsistent  ?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes

Comment: Probably try some hardcoded delays : `sleep(2)` - Is application under development ?

Comment: I add time.sleep(20) between each line, didn't solve... I will logout/login every time I get the problem, it's the only solution I see

Comment: We are hovering so we need move_to_element for sure.. then we should  use Explicit wait rest is all upto locators which is still okay. Not sure why it's not consistent.

Comment: As you said, it's possible that the problem comes from the web application

Comment: yes it could be from application, Is there a way to restart the backend component and test ?

Comment: I'm not the one running the application, it's actually the help desk used between the client and my company

Comment: try to show this inconsistency to your lead or  manager, there's nothing much we can do